# Is the function continuous at x=0?

Tags: analysis

Check if the function $f$ is continuous.
$f(x)=$\begin{matrix}
0 & ,x=0\\ 
\frac{1}{[\frac{1}{x}]} & ,0<x\leq 1 
\end{matrix}.

For $0<x\leq 1$,,f is continuous because it is fraction of continuous functions.
How can I check if it is continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: Is cont. from the right, you mean?

Comment: Yes,I think so!

Comment: good to see that $x\in (0,1]\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{x}\in [1,+\infty)$

Answer (score 2):

$$|f(x) - f(0)| =  |\frac 1 {[\frac 1 x]} - 0| = |\frac 1 {[\frac 1 x]}| = \frac 1 {[\frac 1 x]} \le \frac 1 {\frac 1 x} =  x  = x - 0\;\; (\text {since $x > 0$ and $\frac 1 {[\frac 1 x]} \le \frac 1 {\frac 1 x}$})$$

Given any $\epsilon \gt 0 $ however small, $\exists \ \delta( = \epsilon) \gt 0 $ such that $|f(x) - f(0)| \lt \epsilon$ whenever $x = x - 0 \lt \delta$

$\implies \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = f(0)\implies f$ is right-continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: In the denominator we have `[1/x]` in the function rules. :)

Comment: @B. S. : Not following that.. Did I miss something? Could you explain please..

Comment: [1/x] is the integer part of 1/x..

Comment: Alright.. Then isn't it true that $\frac 1 {[\frac 1 x]} \le \frac 1 {\frac 1 x}$

Comment: @Ishfaaq Yes!And do we also know that $\frac{1}{[\frac{1}{x}]}\geq 0$ ?

Comment: @evinda: Actually $ 0 \lt x \le 1 \implies 1 \le \frac 1 x \implies  1 \le [\frac{1}{x}] \implies \frac{1}{[\frac{1}{x}]} \ge 0$

Comment: And @evinda that made me realise my wording wasn't too great. I edited my answer again. Looks alright now me thinks..